# Firefox can't establish a connection to 'x' server.(I've already allowed Tor through my Firewall

Tags: windows, firefox

I've been getting this error on way too many sites, and other than allowing Tor through Windows Firewall, I do not have the expertise to fix this issue, so I turn to you guys. Help, please?

Comment: Are you using the latest Tor Browser Bundle? Or are you trying a different setup? Are these sites onion sites or 'clearnet' sites - Does trying to access mainstream sites like http://www.wikipedia.org work?

Answer (score 0):

If you can connect to some/most sites but not all, then your Tor setup is healthy. (Unless you have added restrictions to your torrc, but I guess you have not.) Most likely explanation would be that these sites have blocked traffic from Tor exit nodes.